# How do we remove duplicate data from BigQuery and save it to another table which has much attribute

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have uploaded the 99,628 rows in Google BigQuery.
The schema has suppose, company_name, phone, email, address, city, state etc.
I want to keep only distinct rows by `company_name` with most attributes.
If i have the rows as

`Microsoft | 2355 |`

`Microsoft | 1234 | ms@example.com | seatle | XYZ | KC`

`Microsoft | 2355 | any@example.com`

I would like to keep the 2nd row, as it has the highest attribute.

I Tried with the below query but it only returns me distinct results not one with highest attribute.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY company_name)
      row_number
  FROM `local-bastion-154121.Property_Dataset.pmDATA`
)
WHERE row_number = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting "with highest attribute" to mean the row with the most non-NULL values in it for a particular `company_name`. You should be able to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.new_table AS
SELECT
  company_name,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT (company_name))
    ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r': null'))
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM dataset.existing_table AS t
GROUP BY company_name
```

As an example over sample data:

```
WITH existing_table AS (
  SELECT 'Microsoft' AS company_name, 2355 AS x, NULL AS email, NULL AS city, NULL AS y, NULL AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 1234, 'ms@example.com', 'seattle', 'XYZ', 'KC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 2355, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)
SELECT
  company_name,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT (company_name))
    ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ':null'))
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM existing_table AS t
GROUP BY company_name
```

The benefit of using this trick and counting `NULL` values using `SPLIT` in conjunction with `TO_JSON_STRING` is that you don't need to write the list of other columns explicitly. What it does is to build a struct of all columns except for `column_name`, and to order by the number of `NULL` values in the row in ascending order, meaning that you get the row with the most filled-in values for each `company_name`.

Comment: Thanks! :) 
Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider slightly different translation of "with highest attribute" by introducing weight per field as for example I would expect that having `email` is more important than `city`, `state` so just one field would overweight two fields for me

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and attempts to should you weighted approach

```
#standardSQL
WITH weights AS (
  SELECT 'phone' field, 4 weight UNION ALL
  SELECT 'email', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'city', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'address', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'state', 7
)
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(t) r,
    SUM(weight) score
  FROM `local-bastion-154121.Property_Dataset.pmDATA` t
  CROSS JOIN weights w 
  WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), CONCAT(r'', field, '":"?(.*?)"?[,}]')) != 'null'
  GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(t)
)
GROUP BY r.company_name
```

You can test, play with this using sample data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Microsoft' company_name, 2355 phone, NULL email, NULL city, NULL address, NULL state UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 1234, NULL, 'seattle', 'XYZ', 'KC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 2355, 'any@example.com', NULL, NULL, NULL
), weights AS (
  SELECT 'phone' field, 4 weight UNION ALL
  SELECT 'email', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'city', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'address', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'state', 7
)
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(t) r,
    SUM(weight) score
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  CROSS JOIN weights w 
  WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), CONCAT(r'', field, '":"?(.*?)"?[,}]')) != 'null'
  GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(t)
)
GROUP BY r.company_name
```

with result

```
Row company_name    phone   email           city    address state    
1   Microsoft       2355    any@example.com null    null    null
```

As you can see here, winner has less available attributes than other row because it has more "valuable" attribute

You can see score using below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Microsoft' company_name, 2355 phone, NULL email, NULL city, NULL address, NULL state UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 1234, NULL, 'seattle', 'XYZ', 'KC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Microsoft', 2355, 'any@example.com', NULL, NULL, NULL
), weights AS (
  SELECT 'phone' field, 4 weight UNION ALL
  SELECT 'email', 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'city', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'address', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'state', 7
)
SELECT 
  ANY_VALUE(t).*,
  SUM(weight) score
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
CROSS JOIN weights w 
WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), CONCAT(r'', field, '":"?(.*?)"?[,}]')) != 'null'
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(t)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

so scores are

```
Row company_name    phone   email           city    address state   score   
1   Microsoft       2355    any@example.com null    null    null    104  
2   Microsoft       1234    null            seattle XYZ     KC      14   
3   Microsoft       2355    null            null    null    null    4
```

Comment: Thanks :) It was of great help. 
I wanted to weight that attribute, but never thought i can have query as this way too.

Comment: sure. come back and vote up the answer when you get enough reputation here o)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub query counting for each row the number of filled columns, then you sort :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY company_name ORDER BY columns_filled DESC)
          row_number
  FROM (
        SELECT *, 
        IF(uppose !="", 1,0) + IF(company_name !="", 1,0) + IF(phone !="", 1,0) + 
        IF(email !="", 1,0) + IF(address !="", 1,0) + IF(city !="", 1,0) + 
        IF(state !="", 1,0) + <SAME FOR EACH FIELD> as columns_filled
        FROM `local-bastion-154121.Property_Dataset.pmDATA`
   )
)
WHERE row_number = 1
```

That's it :)